# How to make bold font NSString value?

Tags: ios, string, fonts, bold

In my iOS application, how can I make bold font in NSString value? I used below code for making bold font text in NSString value, but showing error

like this:

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>     "_kCIAttributeName",

```
NSString *boldFontName = [[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12] fontName];
NSString *yourString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@",key,@":",@" "];
NSRange boldedRange = NSMakeRange(22, 4);

NSMutableAttributedString *attrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:yourString];

[attrString beginEditing];
[attrString addAttribute:kCIAttributeName value:boldFontName range:boldedRange];

[attrString endEditing];

NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",attrString,[dic objectForKey:key]];
```

How do I make bold font in string?

Answer (score 0):

the `NSString` is for store a **simple texts** without any font formatting.

the `UILabel` has a `font` property, you can use it to set the visible text's font on the `UI`, but the `UILabel` can work with one format only and the whole text gets the same font and style.

---

if you really want to use a kind of rich text document, you should create a `UIWebView` class and you can show any document inside with the standard `HTML` tags.

---

#### **UPDATE**

the `UILabel` can store [attributed string](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilabel/1620542-attributedtext) since iOS6, which gives you a chance to show rich-formatted text in one single `UILabel` instance, even using various fonts or sizes, etc...

Comment: Ok, i understand, if any way to show text some text bold and another some text normal.   like string_1: String_2; i want make string_1: bold font

Comment: for this for the two different strings you have to use different `UILabel` instances with different fonts.

Comment: sorry, i need to us only one label. how can achieve if any other way. Thanks for your replying.

Comment: you simply **cannot** do this with one `UILabel`. there is no other way to achieve the detailed formatted text just using more `UILabel` or using an `UIWebView`... or you could try to find a 3rd part code for you wishes anywhere on the net.